# Transferring music files, via router, from PC to network audio receiver?

Tags: sound, music, sharing, media

I have a Yamaha R-N500 network receiver hardwired to an ethernet router (Linksys). It currently communicates with the web for such things as net radio and Pandora. Is there a straightforward means to link my Linux-based PC, also on the same router, to the audio receiver? I want the receiver to be able to access and play music files (ex: mp3) off the PC. The receiver has a 'server' option as one of the input selections. I can also read all the data assignments at the receiver as far as addressing is concerned. The big mystery is how to actually implement the media sharing between the two devices.

Answer (score 0):

Getting some search on internet i could find that this model is DLNA capable and Airplay(Apple) capable. So you must install some app to stream your media over your network. Some examples:

**Kodi media center (aka XBMC)**

**Media Tomb**

Comment: The owners manual indicates that the receiver can be switched to the server input mode and then "see" the music files available to play on the pc. Right now when you select "Server" on the receiver unit it says [NO CONTENT] on the display. I didn't think a streaming app was the way to go with this. VLC player is definitely not a good choice after trying it.

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu 18.04LTS install Rygel (sudo apt install rygel) and add folders, any folders in the standard Settings menu under Sharing.
[image]

No need to fiddle this is standard in Ubuntu 18 and up using the standard Settings GUI.

You can add sftp, dav, davs, ssh, dropbox, google drive, smb, sftps, nfs and even AppleTalk afp:// shares.

Then if you need to share internet radio stations over DLNA this is possible too.

To stream SomaFM over DLNA (Rygel) to your DLNA client (Yamaha receiver or any other player) you need to edit rygel.conf. Not just any rygel.conf but the one in /home/$Username$/.config/rygel.conf. (Where $Username$ is your username.)

Go to the section [GstLaunch] and edit the changes as seen below.

I have added the complete section of a working version of rygel.conf here.

```
[GstLaunch]
enabled=true
launch-items=audiotestsrc;soma;drone

audiotestsrc-title=Audiotestsrc
audiotestsrc-mime=audio/x-wav
audiotestsrc-launch=audiotestsrc ! wavenc

soma-title=SomaFM SpaceStation soma-mime=audio/mp4
soma-launch=souphttpsrc iradio-mode=false location=http://ice2.somafm.com/spacestation-128-aac

drone-title=SomaFM Dronezone drone-mime=audio/mpeg
drone-launch=souphttpsrc iradio-mode=false location=http://ice2.somafm.com/dronezone-256-mp3
```

No need to change anything on the Yamaha, just turn on and press the server button. Or go to server if no button has been assigned (YET:) Both Rygel and the Yamaha are DLNA compatible.

Answer (score 0):

**Ubuntu 19.10**’s new ‘**Media Sharing**’ toggle in `Settings > Sharing` means you can share media photos, videos and music over your local network. It all works using the **ubiquitous DLNA/UPnP protocols** and your local network — no third-party cloud server or media centre set-up required. (Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server)).

1. To **activate** media sharing in Ubuntu 19.10 just pop open the main Settings app and select the ‘Sharing’ option in the sidebar:
   [image]
2. **Click on the ‘Media Sharing’ option** that’s greyed out in the main pane. A small modal dialogue will appear:
   [image]
3. Slide the switcher in the header bar of the modal dialogue to ‘On’, and then select a network from the list to share your media on.
   *Disclaimer: DLNA sharing isn’t a secure way to share media. Everyone on the same network can access (but not edit/delete) shared media.*
4. You’ll notice that 3 folders are shared by default: Pictures, Videos and Music. **If you don’t want to share one/any of these just remove them** from the list using the x ion to the right of the folder name.
5. **To add your own media sources** just scroll down the dialogue and hit the + button. Then use the folder picker to navigate to and select a different folder on your system. Repeat the process to add additional directories.

**For more details,** please read [the article on OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/10/ubuntu-dlna-media-sharing-server).

It looks like it is based on [Rygel](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/Rygel) and this tool is now integrated in Ubuntu. Be careful [it sometimes autostarts by default/mistake after upgrading to 19.10](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/rygel/+bug/1848692) but a fix is on its way (Nov 2019). (Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2019/11/rygel-autostart-media-sharing-bug-ubuntu).)

Comment: ***DO NOT*** post the same answer to many questions - instead, if the questions are similar enough, flag the questions as duplicates rather than post the same answer to many questions.